# Linux: Lookup for an VNC Server that feels like RDP

Tags: linux, x11, users, vnc, rdp

I'm running a linux server somewhere in the internet. The linux server didn't have a display or keyboard attached. I want to use it as always online linux terminal server. I after some testing, xrdp works great. But now I'm looking into something more performant, since xrdp feels laggy and has some fps drops. Since the MacOS RDP Client does not support RemoteFX I need an alternative to RDP. freerdp doesn't work well on macos, too.

I installed X11VNC, started X11VNC from my RDP session, then I connect to the VNC Server and the performance issues are gone. But unlike xrdp, X11VNC can't start a X session.

Now I'm looking for xrdp like VNC server. On first connection, it should start a X session and persistent until I locked out.

Running X11VNC on display 0 with a display manager is my fallback situation but it wouldn't handle multiple remote user (one session per user) at the same time like RDP does.

I also look into x2go but I do not want to go with it.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking over on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I like using [xpra](http://xpra.org/).  It has clients for windows and macOS too, it’s open source but can use some codecs that are closed if available, and supports a bunch of features you see in rdp servers.

Plus it has a bunch of different protocols that it supports, including ssh.

Comment: Thanks I ll look into it if it's fit.

Comment: Did you get server side OpenGL? I follow https://xpra.org/trac/wiki/Usage/OpenGL replace xvfb with xdummy but it looks like xdummy doesn't support DRI2 (using ubuntu 20.04). xrdp does support DRI2 results that all application have gpu acceleration.